# Is it safe to use EMP devices near agent Sharp?

Tags: invisible-inc

Is it safe to use EMP devices near agent Sharp, or will they end up knocking him out? According to [his bio](http://invisibleinc.wikia.com/wiki/Agents), he's almost entirely a cyborg, so I'm not sure:

> It is arguable whether or not the human being born as Alex McTeague
>   still exists. Driven by an obsession with perfecting his form, he has
>   replaced most of his parts with a mechanical or vat-grown replacement.
>   Originally funding his transhumanism through corporate bounty hunting,
>   he joined Invisible when his augmentation ambitions grew beyond what
>   is available on the open market.

Comment: As far as I can see, an EMP near Sharp should be allright. At least there's no character trait that says "this character is prone to EMPs". However, there could be another place where they've included that behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

EMP devices have no effect on Sharp or any of the other agents or their augments.

They do shutdown guards heart monitors though so you can use them as a way to avoid increasing the alarm level when killing guards.